# I am facing problem in termux when i try to open config json what to do

Tags: termux

Hey guys I have been downloaded a tool from github.
It's tik tok view bot but i didn't know how to open config.json file

Answer (score 0):

not every bot that works on pc will work on mobile, but to open this file and configure it, just use `nano config.json` if you don't have it installed, write `pkg install nano`